# Send Variable from AJAX table to ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ajax, model-view-controller

I understand the topic is relatively common, but I've spent a LONG time trying to solve this issue with pre-existing posts and I have come up with no luck to solving my issue.
I have got a Homepage with a small database of "Safes", When a user clicks on one of the safes, it should take them to the "Items" Database view and show ONLY the items of the safe they clicked on. However, instead it shows no results? (I have got the items table to display ALL results, so I know it is not an issue with the database). More baffling is that the "data" I wish to use as the filter does show properly in the URL, so that should be fine too?
Any help would be MUCH appreciated... Thanks in advance peeps! :)

[image: Homepage menu select]
[image: The empty table view with URL]

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $('#CBR').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": '/Home/GetSafe',
                "type": "get",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [

                { "data": "Safe_ID", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Department_ID", "autoWidth": true },
                {
                    "data": "Safe_ID", "width": "50px", "render": function (selectedSafe) {

                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/Home/GetSafeItems',
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: { selectedSafe: selectedSafe },
                            type: "GET",
                            success: function (data) {

                                if (data.success) {
                                    alert(data.message);
                                }                                          
                            },
                            error: function (xhr) {
                                alert(selectedSafe);
                            }
                        });
                        return '<a href="/home/safeItems/' + selectedSafe + '">Open Safe</a>';
                    }
                }
            ]
        })
```

HOMEPAGE VIEW (above)

```
public ActionResult GetSafeItems(string selectedSafe)
    {
        using (CBREntities2 dc = new CBREntities2())
        {
            var safeItem = dc.Items.Where(a => a.Safe_ID == selectedSafe).Select(s => new {
                Serial_Number = s.Serial_Number,
                Safe_ID = s.Safe_ID,
                Date_of_Entry = s.Date_of_Entry,
                Title_subject = s.Title_subject,
                Document_Type = s.Document_Type,
                Sender_of_Originator = s.Sender_of_Originator,
                Reference_Number = s.Reference_Number,
                Protective_Marking = s.Protective_Marking,
                Number_recieved_produced = s.Number_recieved_produced,
                copy_number = s.copy_number,
                Status = s.Status,
                Same_day_Loan = s.Same_day_Loan
            }).ToList();

        //    var safeItems = dc.Items.Where(a => a.Safe_ID).Select(s => new { Safe_ID = s.Safe_ID, Department_ID = s.Department_ID, User_ID = s.User_ID }).ToList();
            return Json(new { data = safeItem }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Controller (above)

```
@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Items</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto" class="tablecontainer">
    <a class="popup btn btn-primary" href="/home/SaveItem/0" style="margin- 
 bottom:20px; margin-top:20px">Add new Item </a>
    <table id="CBR-Item">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Serial Number</th>
                <th>Safe ID</th>
                <th>Date of Entry</th>
                <th>Title/Subject</th>
                <th>Document type</th>
                <th>Sender of Originator</th>
                <th>Reference Number</th>
                <th>Protective Marking</th>
                <th>Number recieved/produced</th>
                <th>Copy number</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Same-Day Loan</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $('#CBR-Item').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": '/Home/GetSafeItems',
                "type": "get",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [

                { "data": "Serial_Number", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Safe_ID", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Date_of_Entry", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Title_subject", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Document_Type", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Sender_of_Originator", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Reference_Number", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Protective_Marking", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Number_recieved_produced", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "copy_number", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Status", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Same_day_Loan", "autoWidth": true },
                {
                    "data": "Serial_Number", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                        return '<a class="popup" href="/home/SaveItem/' + data + '">Edit</a>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    "data": "Serial_Number", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                        return '<a class="popup" href="/home/DeleteItem/' + data + '">Delete</a>';
                    }
                }
            ]
        })
        $('.tablecontainer').on('click', 'a.popup', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            OpenPopup($(this).attr('href'));
        })
        function OpenPopup(pageUrl) {
            var $pageContent = $('<div/>');
            $pageContent.load(pageUrl, function () {
                $('#popupForm', $pageContent).removeData('validator');
                $('#popupForm', $pageContent).removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
            });
            $dialog = $('<div class="popupWindow" style="overflow:auto"></div>')
                .html($pageContent)
                .dialog({
                    draggable: false,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    model: true,
                    title: 'Popup Dialog',
                    height: 550,
                    width: 600,
                    close: function () {
                        $dialog.dialog('destroy').remove();
                    }
                })

            $('.popupWindow').on('submit', '#popupForm', function (e) {
                var url = $('#popupForm')[0].action;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: $('#popupForm').serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.status) {
                            $dialog.dialog('close');
                            oTable.ajax.reload();
                        }
                    }
                })

                e.preventDefault();
            })
            $dialog.dialog('open');
        }
    })
</script>
```

Main safe View (above)

I have not inlcuded the safe view as that element works usually without the filter and is calling to the controller method. But can upload if needed.

Amendment: I have almost solved the post issue... but the post won't actually reach the controller (it just keeps tripping the error value in the code Below)

```
{
                    "data": "Safe_ID", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {                           
                        return '<a class="safeLink" href="/home/safeItems/' + data + '">Open Safe</a>';
                       // return { selectedSafe: selectedSafe }


                    }
                }
            ]
        })


        $('.tablecontainer').on('click', 'a.safeLink', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var whatWhat = "SEC-1000";
            var selectedSafeZZ = { theSafe: whatWhat };
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/GetSafeItems',
                data: JSON.stringify(selectedSafeZZ),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert("Boohooo");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call has nothing to do with anchor tag link. So do you have any method in home controller which returns data to view like viewresult.?

Can you paste your complete controllers code

Comment: Hi, I have pasted the main table view page above now. The view will work normally (but will show ALL items in the table, whereas Im trying to get it to only show the items in the safe I clicked now). The Display of the view is being controlled by the "Actionresult GetSafeItems" in the controller (posted above) but I can't get the selected href to post to the controller to manage... if that makes sense? Sorry Im still trying to learn the ropes myself!

Comment: Here `"ajax": {
                "url": '/Home/GetSafeItems',
                "type": "get",
                "datatype": "json"
            }, ` you are not actually passing the selected string to server.. so if can can put a debug point in the method getsafeitems, you'll see an empty string

Comment: In the action method for /home/safeitem/value... Read this value and assign it to a view bag and then in the view on the js you can assign this viewbag value to a js variable and then you can send it to server side method GetSafeItems as a query string or path param

Comment: Hi Pavan ok I think I follow what you are saying. Could you please show me how I would do that in code? This really is the first time I've touched on AJAX. Thankyou so much for your help by the way!